# Silverlight 5 custom control is not working propelry

Tags: c#, custom-controls, silverlight-5.0

Whats wrong with this code. I am completely clueless.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class PercentFiller: StackPanel 
    {
        public Rectangle _FillerRectangle = null;

        public PercentFiller()
        { 
            _FillerRectangle = new Rectangle();
            _FillerRectangle.Height = this.Height;
            _FillerRectangle.Width = 20;

            _FillerRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, new Binding() {
                Source = this,
                Path = new PropertyPath("FillColorProperty"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay 
            });
            this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray); 
            this.Children.Add(_FillerRectangle);
            this.UpdateLayout();

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FillColor",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(Compressor),
            new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 134, 134, 134))));

        [Description("Gets or sets the fill color")]
        public Brush FillColor
        {
            get { return (Brush) GetValue(FillColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue (FillColorProperty, value); }
        } 
    }
}
```

The Rectangle Control is not getting displayed, when i add this control to another project. Please somebody help me fixing this issue.

Comment: You can achieve the same result through `<StackPanel Background="#FF(lightgray rgb here)"><Rectangle Fill="#FF(fill rgb)" Height="20" /></StackPanel>` no need for a custom control

Comment: Just i am trying to learn the Custom controls concept through some examples. so i have tried this with no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the binding wrong (your `_FillerRectangle` has no `DataContext`).
Also, you can pass the dependency property itself to the `PropertyPath`.

Try changing your binding like this:

```
_FillerRectangle.DataContext = this; //#1: add this line
_FillerRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(FillColorProperty), // #2: no longer a string
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
});
```

The `DataContext` "tells" the binding where the dependency property you're binding is located.

Also, there's an error in your `DependencyProperty` declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FillColor",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(Compressor), // <- ERROR ! should be typeof(PercentFiller)
    new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 134, 134, 134))));
```

The marked line should be the type of the property's containing object, so in this case it should read `typeof(PercentFiller)`.

UPDATE:

I forgot to add: `StackPanel` doesn't have a size per-se, so:

```
_FillerRectangle.Height = this.Height;
```

Is meaningless in this context. Either set a fixed size *or* change your control to inherit `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`.

Comment: I have changed it, but still same behavior. I am able to setup background color for the Stack panel (parent), but not for the Rectangle (Child)

Comment: Issues list further expanded.

Comment: i have done some thing stupid. After i set the height, it seems working. Thanks Alex!!

Comment: You're welcome, and remember to mark answer as accepted if it solves the issue, to let future bystanders know it.